# Question about transfer data between specific physical memory and NVME

Tags: linux, performance, io, mmap

I'm trying to transfer data from specific reserved physical memory to my NVME, IIUC, there are 3 steps:

1. In the kernel driver, the reserved-memory (specified physical address and size in dts) is exposed to the userspace through the mmap of file_operation. The specific driver implementation can use memremap to map pa to va, and then use remap_pfn_range or nopage to build page table ( There is room for tunning because the two schemes have their own advantages and disadvantages, but IMO it will not have large impact because io is not involved here)
2. Then the userspace application uses the mmap(2) on device fd to obtain the mapped buffer A
3. Write the above buffer A to the file. There are various methods for this step, mmap, write, io_uring, aio, libaio, etc. Some can support direct io, and some cannot (mmap for example).

Question:

1. Are steps 1, 2, and 3 all correct?
2. For step 1 and 2, are there any other solutions except for mmap?
3. I'm not really sure about can I use io_uring to write from buffer A(come from mmap) to disk file, please tell me if you know.

Comment: you might want to look into the `splice` syscall, which can copy data between file descriptors without your userland having to touch the data. Looks to me it can replace 2. and 3. with a single step.

Comment: will give splice and copy_file_ranges a try. BTW if I use them, I believe should also implement .splice_read|write and .copy_file_ranges for file_operations.